# ssl is invalid ClearDB Heroku Django

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, cleardb

I can't connect my ClearDb to Django app on Heroku, show me this error.

[image]

Comment: Try to add `del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']` right after `django_heroku.settings(locals())` in your settings file.

Comment: Glad it helped! I've posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add to your settings file:

```
del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']
```

right after

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: it's unveliable that heroku docs itself does not explain this issue